# Persistently increase usbfs_memory_mb on RPI4 running Ubuntu 19

Tags: usb, boot, ubuntu, pi-4, usb3

I am working with a 4gb RaspberryPI4 and it's running a USB3 Flir Blackfly. Out of the box, the setting of `usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb` @ 16 isn't enough to get a stream from the camera. Increasing the value to 1024 manually in `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb` works as expected but does not persist over power cycles/reboots.

I found some information about setting the value by updating `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" ... usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb=XXXX"` in grub default, but the device isn't booting from grub. This led me to look for `/boot/cmdline.txt` which doesn't exist in the firmware currently on the device. Not a huge deal, I was able to find `btcmd.txt` which looks to do the same thing.

After adding either of the following to `btcmd.txt`;

- `usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb=1024`
- `setenv bootargs "usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb=1024"`

Neither one worked.

I do not want to have to convert the install to grub, and I would like to avoid having to write a start script that updates `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb` when the desktop boots.

Is there something I'm missing here or is there another place to persistently set this value?

Comment: If using the kernel command line doesn't work, the next easiest way would be to do it via systemd in rc.local or some simple custom service.

Comment: Adding `usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb=1024` to `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` on an 18.04 instance does work, took a couple reboots for it to hook for some reason. On 19 i've had zero luck with trying to set this value at boot, either through scripting or rc.local, totally possible i'm the broken part of the equation here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `rc.local` which runs commands on boot. Test and confirmed working on my pi4:

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local` to open rc.local

Then add the following above the comment line about IP's:

`sudo sh -c 'echo 1024 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb' &` (the ampersand is important!)

CTRL+X and Y to save. `sudo reboot` to test, then confirm with `cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb` which should print `1024`

Comment: Also ubuntu uses systemd to mange services. So you should never suggest to use `/etc/rc.local` anymore. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.